# I don't understand the pre-increment part in this code

Tags: php

Can anyone elexplain to me why the output of this code is 22 not 21?

```
$x=10;
$x+=++$x;
echo $x;
```

Comment: First, x is set to 10, then ++ sets it to 11, finally 11 is added to itself, which is 22.

Comment: Can you explain why you expect it to be 21?

Comment: The `++` go after to get 21. https://3v4l.org/NMbcV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$x += ++$x;
```

The right-hand side of this assignment is evaluated first:

1. increment `$x` → `$x` is now `11`, result of expression `++$x` is `11`
2. take the value of `$x` (`11`) and add the result of step 1 to it → `22`
3. assign the result of step 2 to `$x`

Answer (score 4):

x is being incremented by the stored incremented value of x.

```
x += (x = x + 1).
```

Answer (score 1):

Internally, this is evaluated as:

```
# op          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------
1 ASSIGN                   !0, 10
2 PRE_INC          $2      !0
3 ASSIGN_ADD    0          !0, $2
4 ECHO                     !0
```

1. Assign **10** to `$x` (referred to above as **!0**)
2. Pre-increment `$x`, i.e.

   - Add **1** to `$x`
   - Return the new result (**11**)
3. Increase `$x` (now **11**) by the return value from step 2 (also **11**)
4. Echo the result (**22**)

(Edited the VLD output for readability, see the full version here: https://3v4l.org/mftI4/vld#output)

Answer (score 1):

Its all about order of operations.

$a+=$b is just a shorthand for $a = $a + $b. So now, "unroll" your 2nd line with that knowledge:

```
$x = $x + (++$x);
```

To assign value to $x, we must 1st evaluate right side of the assignment. To do that, we need first to perform the ++ operation, only then our variables on the right are ready to be added.

So what is operator ++ in this context? It is in turn a shorthand for a function, that does something similar to this:

```
function preIncrement(&$variable) {
    $variable = $variable + 1;
    return $variable;
}
```

Note that variable is a reference (&$variable, rather than $variable). What that means is that inside that function, if we modify variable, it will modify the variable that was passed to it, OUTSIDE. So when we pass $x, the function increases $x and then returns some number value. That number value is being replaced in the right side of the assignment.
So, when that line really looks like is:

```
$x = $x + postIncrement($x);
```

So, to evaluate we need to first execute the function in the assignment and get the functions return value. It happens to be 11. Great, now we know we need to add 11 to $x.

```
$x = $x + 11;
```

Great, lets just read current value of $x and we can assign. $x is 11. postIncrement function increased it to 11 when we executed it. So:

```
$x = 11 + 11;
```

So now, $x is 22.

Lets compare that to post incrementation:

```
$x+=$x++;
```

Unrolling += ...

```
$x = $x + $x++;
```

As before, we need to get return value of $x++ before we can evaluate. Post incrementation looks something like this:

```
function postIncrement(&$variable) {
    $oldValue = $variable;
    $variable = $variable + 1;
    return $oldValue;
}
```

So it takes our $x, increases its value, but returns the original value. As a result, the $x++ gets evaluated as 10. Now we arrive at:

```
$x = $x + 10;
```

Ok, lets evaluate $x. $x is 11. Post increment increased it when we executed it. So:

```
$x = 11 + 10;
```

So $x is 21 in that case.

Hope this helps you.